# Getting invalid ELF header issue while loading cython module

Tags: python, optimization, fastapi, cython

I tried running cython compile time optimization on FastAPI serving layer in python during ML Model inferencing.
Instead of loading plain python module for ML Model , I tried loading cython compile ML Module in FastAPI Server.

I am getting below error while loading ML Model while running on Mac OS Monterey ( Version 12.5)

Getting invalid ELF header issue

**Command to used to compile python file**

python setup.py build_ext --inplace

**Content of setup.py file**

from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
setup(ext_modules = cythonize('v2/model.pyx','v2/model_config.pyx','v2/utils.pyx'),
extra_compile_args=["-mmacosx-version-min=10.9", "-stdlib=libc++"],
extra_link_args=["-mmacosx-version-min=10.9", "-stdlib=libc++"],
)

**File which I has trying to load in python code**
model.cpython-310-darwin.so

Any help would be appreciated here

1. I tried in normal Mac laptop ( without M1 chip) , faced same issue there.
2. Also , trying changing -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 setting as per Mac version , it did not help to me.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to load/compile with a shared object file, you might need to specify it in the libraries argument of the setup file. For example if I have a file called `libcalg.so` and want to dynamically link with my cython code, you'd need something like this.

```
ext_modules = cythonize([
Extension(
    "queue", 
    sources=["queue.pyx"],
    libraries=["calg"]) # would be libcalg.so somewhere in usr/local/lib
])
```

Usually shared objects files are prefixed with an `l` so C/C++ knows where to look for it in the `usr/local/lib` directory. If you're just trying to use the functions in `model.cpython-310-darwin.so` you'll need to dynamically link it. Hopefully this helps